# How can I trigger a function by clicking a div which is hidden in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, visibility

I have a div in Javascript, which is initially hidden.Now I want this div to show up again when I click on it by guessing its position, since it is not visible to me, but I am unable to trigger the Javascript function that will make it visible again. So what is the alternate way of achieving the same.

Example code is as follows:

```
<div id="box"style="width:400px; height:300px; background-color:black; visibility:hidden" onclick="show(box)">
```

And the function is as below:

```
function show(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

But above doesn't work, please suggest an alternate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the display to none or the visibility to hidden, I'd change the opacity instead:

```js
function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width:400px; height:300px; background-color:black; opacity:0" onclick="show('box')">
```

Note also that you need quotes in your event handler (`onclick="show('box')"`), otherwise the browser assumes that `box` is a variable.

Comment: Ya I knew that, just typed the example code in hurry. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use doucument click event listener (or parent of box) and check if mouse pointer in the box area then set visibility to visible.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.pageX <= 400 && e.pageY <= 300) {
         document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});
```